# Error with Curl to get keywordsideas with Google ads api

Tags: curl, google-ads-api

I'm trying to use curl with google ads api after generating access token through curl also and try to use this command

```
curl -i --request POST https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers/2260416591:generateKeywordIdeas \ --header "Content-Type:application/json" \ --header "login-customer-id: 2260416591\ --header "developer-token: z2sb0uyekDzkMbiyNpAImg" \ --header "Authorization: Bearer ya29.A0ARrdaM9-2ZnG42VSl3mfrst_A8Rj5UoR6J0kJlMo-wGpCCgcOH1srTaSCKuVnHAoKHUPjx52bkPNUkLb7BydNycv7_6-5cryNOp7EZc6B4QK8vQ5-gI6Zy_XB1eCwIocwh508RIJxIgoPrx0PqOwLXlB332BeA" \ --data '{ "keywordSeed": { "keywords": [ "coffee" ] } }'
```

I get this error

```
HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1564
Date: Thu, 20 Jan 2022 13:07:10 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
curl: (3) nested brace in URL position 192:
ya29.A0ARrdaM9-2ZnG42VSl3mfrst_A8Rj5UoR6J0kJlMo-wGpCCgcOH1srTaSCKuVnHAoKHUPjx52bkPNUkLb7BydNycv7_6-5cryNOp7EZc6B4QK8vQ5-gI6Zy_XB1eCwIocwh508RIJxIgoPrx0PqOwLXlB332BeA \ --data '{ keywordSeed: { keywords: [ coffee ] } }'
```

What's the problem here? for sure this token not working anymore but this error dumped each time I try to use curl to generate keywordsideas through google ads api

Answer (score 0):

--data "{ "keywordSeed": { "keywords": [ "coffee" ] } }"

Enclose it in double quotes instead of single one, and it will run